# LibreOffice Writer: How can portion numbers be automated?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

[image]

So that when the page is duplicated, the following page will display the next numbers and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a custom number range:

1. Put the cursor to the first occurence of the numbering;
2. Menu Insert -> Field -> More Fields...
   [image]
3. Select the "Variables" tab;
4. In the "Type" column, select "Number range";
5. In the "Name" field, overwrite the proposed range Name "Drawing" with a custom name (e.g. "CustomRange1");
6. Hit <kbd>Return</kbd> or <kbd>Insert</kbd>
7. Put the cursor to the next place; hit <kbd>Insert</kbd> again and so on.

Illustration for steps 3-6:

[image]

By default, custom ranges will have arabic numbering. To increment, just insert the same number range field anywhere else in your document (either by using Menu "Insert" -> "Field" -> "More fields" or by copy&paste).